# How do you chain functions using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object that looks like

```
var foundUser = {
    charData: []
}
```

which then I load an object from a database using mysql and then I call

```
_.assignIn(foundUser, rows[0]);
```

But I get a few extra properties that I don't need (this isn't solvable by using select)

So I call

```
foundUser = _.omit(foundUser, ['blah']);
```

But it would be nice if I could just do

```
_.assignIn(foundUser, rows[0]).omit(rows[0], ['blah']);
```

But that throws an error, am I doing it wrong or is there another way this can be done?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#_

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#chain

Answer (score 133, accepted):

To chain with lodash, you first have to wrap the object:

```
_(foundUser).assignIn(rows[0]).omit(['blah']).value();
```

Further clarification:

The `_` creates a lodash object which allows for implicit method chaining. Implicit method chaining means that in certain circumstances it may return a primitive value, in others it may return a lodash object that you need to unwrap by calling `.value()` on it.

If you'd use `_.chain(...)`, you'd be creating a lodash object with explicit method chaining. The result is always a wrapped value and always needs to be unwrapped by calling `.value()` on it.

For further reference here are the links to the documentation:

[Explicit chaining in Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#chain)

[Implicit chaining in Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#lodash)

Comment: Not that I can think of a reason you'd need it, but there's also ` _.chain(foundUser)` if you want to be more explicit about it.

Comment: was going to comment the same, you don't *have* to wrap the object

Comment: @RobM. if you do `_.chain()` you're still wrapping the object, it's just more explicit

Answer (score 47):

As an alternative to the wrap-chain-unwrap pattern (nothing inherently wrong with it, but alternatives are always interesting) there's another way you can check.

Try by leveraging [`_.flow`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flow).

The idea is that every function inside `flow` will receive as input the output of the previous one, which is exactly what you need.
An example, given this data:

```
var foundUser = {
    charData: []
};

var rows = [{ok: 1, blah: 'nope'}];
```

Using [`Lodash FP`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) we can pass the data as last argument. This feature along with the auto-currying of each method in Lodash/fp makes our life easier when composing functions. This means we can have this succinct and expressive code:

```
_.flow(
 _.assign(rows[0]),
 _.omit('blah')
)(foundUser);

// >> {"charData":[],"ok": 1}
```

Using the standard version of Lodash we have to curry those functions ourselves using `_.partial`, and the code will certainly look less terse, but it is still possible to do so:

```
_.flow(
 _.partialRight(_.assign, rows[0]),
 _.partialRight(_.omit, 'blah')
)(foundUser);

// >> {"charData":[],"ok": 1}
```

A great benefit of using flow rather than chaining is that you can easily mix Lodash methods with ***your own custom functions***, since - as said -
all they need is just data as input and data as output, and nothing else:

```
const yourFunction = d => ({ ...d, yourProp: 4 });

_.flow(
 _.assign(rows[0]),
 yourFunction,
 _.omit('blah')
)(foundUser);

// >> {"charData":[],"ok": 1, yourProp: 4}
```

This makes function composition much easier and more flexible and arguably will naturally lead to more expressive code.

Another thing to note. If you are installing and importing only the Lodash methods you use, you will have to add just the `flow` package and not the whole Lodash library as you'd do with chaining.

```
npm i --save lodash.flow
```

Vs

```
npm i --save lodash
```

Perhaps a negligible advantage in many real-world applications where having the full build of Lodash is not a problem and arguably easier to maintain up to date, but very handy in case you are writing a library or a script that will be distributed to use as a third party tool. In that case you will be able to keep your footprint way lower in terms of distributed size.

Lodash methods docs:

- [_.flow](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flow)
- [_.partial](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial)
- [_.partialRight](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partialRight)

Articles worth checking out:

- [Lodash from chaining to piping](https://dev.to/aurelio/up-your-lodash-game-by-going-functional-from-chaining-to-piping-3li8) (disclaimer: I wrote it)
- [3 lodash functions you should be using in your Javascript](http://www.scottmessinger.com/2015/05/19/functional-programming-with-lodash/)
- [Why chaining is a mistake](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba#.dcv5qk552)

A few other things to note:

- In Lodash/fp Flow is aliased as `_.pipe`, so you can pick whichever you prefer.
- You can also use `_.flowRight` (or its `fp` alias `_.compose`) if you prefer right to left composition, as seen in [Ramda's compose](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose).

Example:

```
_.flow(
 _.assign(rows[0]), // #1st to execute
 yourFunction,  // #2
 _.omit('blah'),  // #3
)(foundUser);

// is the same as...

_.flowRight(
 _.omit('blah'), // #3rd to execute
 yourFunction, // #2
 _.assign(rows[0]), // #1
)(foundUser);
```

Comment: Getting expected a function error @Nobita from your examples

Comment: @BabluAhmed ensure you're importing the FP version of Lodash (`import _ from 'lodash/fp` and not the "standard" one (`import _ from 'lodash'`)

Comment: Then @Nobita, mention the code here accordingly version

Comment: @BabluAhmed it is right there in the explanation "Using Lodash FP we can pass ..." and there's a link to the repo. If you feel it should be worded differently feel free to edit, we're on SO after all :). Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

Chain is the best equivalence to pipe in lodash.

```
_.chain(foundUser)
 .assignIn(rows[0])
 .omit(['blah'])
 .value()
```

You can also chain some custom function by `.tap` or `.thru`, e.g.:

```
_.chain(foundUser)
 .assignIn(rows[0])
 .tap(console.log)
 .omit(['blah'])
 .value()
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you ever tried [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide)? It comes with all the same functions, but they are curried and none of them mutates the input.

Because of that, you can compose them in a really nice way.

Example:

```js
import moment from 'moment'
import { compose, filter, groupBy, size, sortBy } from 'lodash/fp'

const fromAdmin = filter({ type: 'admin' })
const groupedByDate = groupBy(message => moment(message.createdAt).format('YYYYMMDD'))
const sorted = sortBy('createdAt')
const unreadByUser = filter({ isReadByUser: false })

const groupedMessages = compose(
  groupedByDate,
  sorted,
  unreadByUser,
  fromAdmin,
)(messages)
```

Comment: I was contemplating using `lodash/fp`, as I have experience with `Ramda`, but there's a downside... documentation is really poor (plus no method comments in Typescript), and no tree shaking during build AFAIK

Comment: Yep. Documentation is bad. But you can read the documentation for `lodash` and invert the order of the parameters. Works 95% of the times. :) For tree shaking, I use https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash

Comment: We don't use babel, but that would be a good option otherwise 