# Lodash concatenate two methods

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is it possible to concatenate two lodash methods? In my case uniqBy and sortBy

Example:

```
const uniquePotentialClients = _.uniqBy(
    [...potentialClients],
    uniqueContact => uniqueContact.phoneNumbers[0].number,
 );

 const sortPotentialClients = _.sortBy(
    [...potentialClients],
    uniqueContact => uniqueContact.givenName,
 );
```

Is it possible two apply these two methods to one collection?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#chain chain is made specifically for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you chain functions using lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590543/how-do-you-chain-functions-using-lodash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

### [Chaining](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#lodash)

This wraps the value you'd be working on and then you can *chain* more operations on it without supplying a parameter. When finished [`.value()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#prototype-value) extracts the final value.

```
const result = _.chain([...potentialClients])
  .uniqBy(uniqueContact => uniqueContact.phoneNumbers[0].number)
  .sortBy(uniqueContact => uniqueContact.givenName)
  .value();
```

### Using functional composition

```
const uniqFn = _.uniqBy(uniqueContact => uniqueContact.phoneNumbers[0].number);
const sortFn = _.sortBy(uniqueContact => uniqueContact.givenName);

const composedFn = _.flow(uniqFn, sortFn);

const result = composedFn([...potentialClients]);
```

This implementation is possible if you're using the [FP release of Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide). If you aren't, then you'd have to apply modifiers to the functions to flip the arguments and make them curried which will make them functional programming friendly, similar to what lodash/fp does. Here is a sample of how this can be done:

```
 //_.curry requires the arity to be declared, passing 2 satisfies both these functions
const makeFpFriendly = f => _.curry(_.flip(f), 2);

const uniqByFpFriendly = makeFpFriendly(_.uniqBy);
const sortByFpFriendly = makeFpFriendly(_.sortBy);
```

Comment: Is it possible to sort numbers after letters in this method?