# How to chain a custom operation for Seq and keeping it lazy and fluent?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Based on question [Create chain in lodash with custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21163594/1140754) I would like to chain my own custom function with the following requirements:

1. Keep fluent
2. Return a Seq
3. Keep lazy behavior

For example consider the sequence `res` resulting from the following query:

```
const src = [0, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 12, 12, 6, 6]
const res = _(src)
    .filter(nr =>  nr % 2 == 0)
    .map(nr => 'nr:' + nr)
console.log(res.value()) // => ['nr:0','nr:6','nr:6','nr:6','nr:12','nr:12','nr:6','nr:6' ]
```

Now, I would like to interleave between `filter()` and `map()`, a new `collapse()` operation which merges series of adjacent elements.

I am implementing `collapse()`  like this:

```
function collapse(src) {
    const res = []
    let prev = undefined
    for(let curr of src) {
        if(prev != curr) {
            prev = curr
            res.push(curr)
        }
    }
    return _(res)
}
```

But this solution does not fulfill requirements:  1. Keep fluent,  and 3. Keep lazy behavior. To use this `collapse()`we have to write:

```
collapse(
    _(src)
    .filter(nr =>  nr % 2 == 0)
)
.map(nr => 'nr: ' + nr) // => [ 'nr: 0', 'nr: 6', 'nr: 12', 'nr: 6' ]
```

Instead, I would like to write: `_(src).filter(nr =>  nr % 2 == 0).collapse().map(nr => 'nr: ' + nr)`

Even worst, the collapse is being performed eagerly.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21165100/1140754) I see that we can extend the lodash prototype with the [mixin](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mixin) utility function. Yet, am not figuring out how can I access the elements of the previous operation (e.g. `filter()`) for being parsed in `collapse()` function?

Comment: A function defined using a mixin should work in a chain. In your example just return res rather than _(res).

Comment: @GruffBunny and where do I get the `src`?

Comment: Chaining will pass the result of the previous operation to the current operation.

Comment: @GruffBunny I am going to try that. Can you tell me where in lodash documentation is describing that behavior?

Comment: Can't find anything in the docs. What chaining does is pass the result of the previous operation as the first parameter. In your case as you only have one parameter the chain would look something like `.filter(...).collapse().map(...)` i.e. no parameter passed to collapse explicitly.

Comment: Have added an answer as it's a bit more clear than code in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mixin will work in a chain and the first parameter passed to the function will be the result of the previous operation:

```
_.mixin( { collapse: function(list){
    const res = []
    let prev = undefined
    for(let curr of list) {
        if(prev != curr) {
            prev = curr
            res.push(curr)
        }
    }
    return res;
}});

const res = _(src)
    .filter(nr =>  nr % 2 == 0)
    .collapse()
    .map(nr => 'nr:' + nr)
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const collapse = start => el => el !== start ? ( start = el, true ) : false;
```

So you can do:

```
_(src).filter( collapse() )
```