# How to insert a 'non-lodash' function into a lodash chain (or simulate conditional)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am very fresh with functional programming concept so perhaps what I'm asking is very simple and/or can't be done.

Let us imagine some code (array, order, count are used as formal parameters in Alt but these also exist in namespace for this example - to keep it more readable. Score is defined elsewhere and it works).

So, the code is aimed to process an object. One of the operations is taking `n` first or last elements (actually an object became an array at that time - `n` is represented by a count variable).

The story is that I have no idea how to inject a function that switches between taking them from the beginning or the end into that lodash chain.

It should replace the `.takeRight` function call. 
I have checked several potential ways of writing it without any practical results. How could it be done? Are there simple methods to use conditionals in such a situations?

```
var Alt = (array,order,count) => {
  const result = (order) ? _.take(array, count) : _.takeRight(array, count);
  return result; 
};


const black = _.chain(array)
.groupBy(score)
.values()
.takeRight(count)
.flatten()
.value();
console.log (black);
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `_.mixin` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163594/create-chain-in-lodash-with-custom-functions

Comment: Yes, that's it. That solved a problem really